# Get number of 'nested' template arguments of a template type in c++

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

How can I get the number of 'nested' template arguments of a type in c++?

I would like to write a function `GetNumberOfTypes<T>()` that returns the number of template arguments of `T`:

```cpp
constexpr int a = GetNumberOfTypes<int>(); //a == 0
constexpr int b = GetNumberOfTypes<std::vector<int>>(); //b == 1
constexpr int c = GetNumberOfTypes<std::tuple<int,int>>(); //c == 2
```

Can this be accomplished somehow? I've messed around with `sizeof...`, but I don't really know what I'm doing...

Comment: The trick here is to "unwrap" the outer argument so that you end up with a list of args to count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might (somehow) do it with specialization:

```
template <typename T>
struct TemplateArity : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0>
{};

template <template <typename...> class C, typename ...Ts>
struct TemplateArity<C<Ts...>> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof...(Ts)>
{};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/57892590967f537f)

We cannot mix in generic way types, non-type and template-template parameters, so `std::array` is not handled for example.